# Java Swing Text Field Height

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write a GUI for a program I already finished which compiles various text files into a complete notebook. One feature of this GUI will be that it has multiple file browsing textareas and buttons in a scroll pane, and more can be added or removed with a plus or minus button.

The problem is, the textarea is defaulting to occupy the remaining space, even if I set a preferred size. Is there any way I can get it to be just the same height as the button or near it at least?

Here is what my GUI looks like now.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Notebook Builder");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(860, 500));

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 500));

        JScrollPane rightPanel = new JScrollPane();
        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 500));

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPanel);

        contentPanel.add(leftPanel);
        contentPanel.add(rightPanel);

        JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Directories");
        headerLabel.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
        headerPanel.add(headerLabel);

        JPanel directoryBrowserPanel = new JPanel();
        directoryBrowserPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(directoryBrowserPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JScrollPane directoryBrowserPanelView = new JScrollPane(directoryBrowserPanel);

        JPanel addOrRemoveButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        addOrRemoveButtonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(addOrRemoveButtonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JButton remove = new JButton("-");
        JButton add = new JButton("+");

        JPanel directoryBrowserFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        directoryBrowserFieldPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(directoryBrowserFieldPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JTextField filePathField = new JTextField();

        JButton fileChooseButton = new JButton("Browse");

        directoryBrowserFieldPanel.add(filePathField);
        directoryBrowserFieldPanel.add(fileChooseButton);
        addOrRemoveButtonPanel.add(remove);
        addOrRemoveButtonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(80, 0)));
        addOrRemoveButtonPanel.add(add);
        directoryBrowserPanel.add(directoryBrowserFieldPanel);
        directoryBrowserPanel.add(addOrRemoveButtonPanel);

        JPanel buildButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton buildButton = new JButton("Build Notebook");
        buildButton.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN ,12));
        buildButtonPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, buildButton);

        leftPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, headerPanel);
        leftPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, directoryBrowserPanelView);
        leftPanel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buildButtonPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sorry if it is a simple question, this is my first time straying from console programs in Java.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi), then consider using a `LayoutManager` other then `BoxLayout`, something like `FlowLayout` or even `GridBagLayout` for example

Comment: FlowLayout worked. Thanks. I guess its just because of a way the layout manager handles height in the different managers? I also didn't use set preferred height.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can answer your own question to help future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Use GridbagLayout instead of BoxLayout. I think it is more useful. Sample code is below

```
int xPos=0;
    int yPos=0;
    directoryBrowserFieldPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    directoryBrowserFieldPanel.add(filePathField, new GridBagConstraints(xPos++, yPos, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));
    directoryBrowserFieldPanel.add(fileChooseButton, new GridBagConstraints(xPos++, yPos, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));
```

ana please take a look to [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)